# How to update the location of installed library on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I previously installed zlib library by "cmake ..", "make" and "make install". By calling function "find_package(zlib)" in CMakeLists.txt, the default installed location is found to be "C:\Program Files (x86)\zlib" . The content of CMakeLists.txt is written as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.4)
project(zlib C)

find_package(ZLIB)
message(STATUS "Found")
message(STATUS "    ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Now I reinstall this library by "cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=D:/TEST_ZLIB/ ..", getting the result as bellow

```
E:\Code\cpp\zlib-1.2.11\build>make install
[ 41%] Built target zlib
[ 46%] Built target minigzip64
[ 85%] Built target zlibstatic
[ 90%] Built target example
[ 95%] Built target minigzip
[100%] Built target example64
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/lib/libzlib.dll.a
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/bin/libzlib.dll
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/lib/libzlibstatic.a
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/include/zconf.h
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/include/zlib.h
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/share/man/man3/zlib.3
-- Installing: D:/TEST_ZLIB/share/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
```

However, function find_package(zlib) still reports the previous location:

```
E:\Code\cpp\test_cmake\build>cmake ..
-- Found
--     C:/Program Files (x86)/zlib/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Code/cpp/test_cmake/build
```

How can I update the location of this library? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `find_package()` call is **cached**, so running it the second time doesn't search actually, but uses the cached value.

CMake cache is contained in `CMakeCache.txt` file located in the binary directory. So you have 3 possibilities for force `find_package` to search again:

1. **Remove** the whole **binary directory**.

   Next invocation of `cmake` will be "fresh": it will search for compiler, all needed packages, and so on.
2. **Remove** `CMakeCache.txt` file from the binary directory.

   Next invocation of `cmake` will be "fresh", same as in the first case.
3. From `CMakeCache.txt` **remove** the **lines**, corresponded to your package.

   E.g., for force `find_package(ZLIB)` to search again, you may remove all entries contained substring "zlib" (case-insensitive).

   Next invocation of `cmake` will use cached settings for compiler, other packages, but search ZLIB again.

The 3d variant requires slightly more actions, but it will result with faster `cmake` call.

The 1st and 2nd variants are easy to perform and their effects are almost identical. They both result in "slow" `cmake` call, which would need to perform all checks again. But you may be sure that you won't leave cached setting in inconsistent case.

When troubleshooting, always choose 1st or 2nd variants!